# using View.isShown shows flickering

Tags: android, android-scrollview

I coded as below in overriden `onScroll` method in order to show "New" icon.

```
public void onScroll(AbsListView absListView, int firstVisibleItem, int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {
    if (user.hasNewPost && !imageViewNew.isShown())
        imageViewNew.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    else   
        imageViewNew.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
}
```

I hardly understand why `imageViewNew` is flickering when I use `isShown()` method. I removed `isShown()` method and it gave stable visibility during onScroll event.

I printed `Log.d(TAG, String.valueOf(imageViewNew.isShown()));` and it really gave true/false accordingly at every scroll event as below.

```
07-06 22:47:10.132    6831-6831/com.sample D/TestViewFragment﹕ false
07-06 22:47:10.192    6831-6831/com.sample D/TestViewFragment﹕ true
07-06 22:47:10.242    6831-6831/com.sample D/TestViewFragment﹕ false
07-06 22:47:10.302    6831-6831/com.sample D/TestViewFragment﹕ true
```

How can it be happened?
Note that it occured from 2.3.6 to 5.0.1, so might be device independent issue.

Below code is `View.isShown()` method in `android.view`.

```
public boolean isShown() {
    View current = this;
    //noinspection ConstantConditions
    do {
        if ((current.mViewFlags & VISIBILITY_MASK) != VISIBLE) {
            return false;
        }
        ViewParent parent = current.mParent;
        if (parent == null) {
            return false; // We are not attached to the view root
        }
        if (!(parent instanceof View)) {
            return true;
        }
        current = (View) parent;
    } while (current != null);

    return false;
}
```

I cannot check which line returns `false` as my Android Studio does not apply breakpoint on the source.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> "I hardly understand why imageViewNew is flickering when I use isShown() method"

`onScroll` method is called several and several times in a row, so let's see the processing "stack":

```
onScroll -> !isShown == true -> 
              setVisibility(View.VISIBLE); // next call !isShow will be false
onScroll -> !isShown == false -> 
              setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE); // next call !isShow will be true
onScroll -> !isShown == true -> 
              setVisibility(View.VISIBLE); // next call !isShow will be false
onScroll -> !isShown == false -> 
              setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE); // next call !isShow will be true
```

on each call you're changing the final value for the comparison. It seems pretty logical to be that it will be flickering.

Maybe you want to call this code in a different method, one that doesn't called several times again and again.